# how to check if one of the array got a value using Ramda

Tags: node.js, ramda.js

hi im trying to check if one of the array got a value and it need to return true

```
input1 =  {   "value": [
    {
      "props": {
        "forest": []
      }
    },
    {
      "props": {
        "forest": [
          {
            "items": "woods"
          }
        ]
      }
    }   ] }

input2 =  {   "value": [
    {
      "props": {
        "forest": []
      }
    },
    {
      "props": {
        "forest": []
      }
    }   ] }
```

the code i tried is R.anyPass to check if one of the value is True and if yes then it return true

```
const forestgotwoods = R.pipe(
    R.path(['value']),
    R.map(R.pipe(
    R.path(['props','forest']),
    R.isEmpty,
    R.not,
    )),
    R.anyPass
);

console.log(forestwoods(input1)); undef
console.log(forestwoods(input2)); undef
```

and I also try it this way

```
const forestgotwoods = R.anyPass(
  [R.pipe(
    R.path(['value']),
    R.map(R.pipe(
    R.path(['props','forest']),
    R.isEmpty,
    R.not,
    ))
)]
);
console.log(forestwoods(input1)); //true
console.log(forestwoods(input2)); //true
```

The result for input1 need to be true

The result for input2 need to be false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use R.any that returns a boolean according to the predicate. R.anyPass accepts an array of predicates, which is not needed here. You can remove the R.anyPass from the start because we don't need the check here.

In addition, you need to check if any any array of `props.forest` is empty, so remove replace R.map with R.any.

```js
const forestgotwoods = R.pipe(
  R.prop('value'), // get the value array
  R.any(R.pipe( // if predicate returns true break and return true, if not return false
    R.path(['props', 'forest']), // get the forest array
    R.isEmpty,
    R.not,
  ))
)

const input1 = {"value":[{"props":{"forest":[]}},{"props":{"forest":[{"items":"woods"}]}}]}
const input2 = {"value":[{"props":{"forest":[]}},{"props":{"forest":[]}}]}

console.log(forestgotwoods(input1)); // true
console.log(forestgotwoods(input2)); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Another option is to use R.all to check if all are empty, and then use R.not to negate the result of R.all:

```js
const forestgotwoods = R.pipe(
  R.prop('value'), // get the value array
  R.all(R.pipe( // if predicate returns true for all, return true, if at least one returns false, return false
    R.path(['props', 'forest']), // get the forest array
    R.isEmpty,
  )),
  R.not // negate the result of R.all
)

const input1 = {"value":[{"props":{"forest":[]}},{"props":{"forest":[{"items":"woods"}]}}]}
const input2 = {"value":[{"props":{"forest":[]}},{"props":{"forest":[]}}]}

console.log(forestgotwoods(input1)); // true
console.log(forestgotwoods(input2)); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Using my 2nd solution with R.propSatisfies (suggested by @Hitmands) generates a short and readable solution:

```js
const forestgotwoods = R.pipe(
  R.prop('value'), // get the value array
  R.all(R.pathSatisfies(R.isEmpty, ['props', 'forest'])), // if all are empty, return true, if at least one return is not, return false
  R.not // negate the result of R.all
)

const input1 = {"value":[{"props":{"forest":[]}},{"props":{"forest":[{"items":"woods"}]}}]}
const input2 = {"value":[{"props":{"forest":[]}},{"props":{"forest":[]}}]}

console.log(forestgotwoods(input1)); // true
console.log(forestgotwoods(input2)); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: R.map and R.anyPass is the wrong way of doing it, thank you for your help now i need to understand how R.all and R.any works to the Ramda site =)

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to the previous answer from @Ori Drori,
you could also leverage `R.useWith` to create a function that operates on both arrays...

```js
const whereForestNotEmpty = R.pathSatisfies(
  R.complement(R.isEmpty), 
  ['props', 'forest'],
);

const findForest = R.pipe(
  R.propOr([], 'value'),
  R.find(whereForestNotEmpty),
);

const find = R.useWith(R.or, [findForest, findForest]);

// ===

const a = {
  "value": [
    {"props":{"forest":[]}},
    {"props":{"forest":[{"items":"woods"}]}}
  ]
}

const b = {
  "value": [
    {"props":{"forest":[]}},
    {"props":{"forest":[]}}
  ]
}

console.log(find(a, b));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

---

**Note**: use `R.complement` to negate predicates

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a simpler, more readable Ramda approach:

```js
const forestHasWoods = where ({
  value: any (hasPath (['props', 'forest', 0]))
})

const input1 = {value: [{props: {forest: []}}, {props: {forest: [{items: "woods"}]}}]};
const input2 = {value: [{props: {forest: []}}, {props: {forest: []}}]}; 

console.log (forestHasWoods (input1))
console.log (forestHasWoods (input2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {where, any, hasPath} = R </script>
```

[`where`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#where) is used to turn a description of an object into a predicate, especially useful in filtering.  [`any`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#any) has been discussed in other answers, and is definitely what you want here rather than [`anyPass`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#anyPass).  And [`hasPath`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#hasPath) reports whether three is a value to be found at this path in the given object..

There is a potential issue here, I suppose.  If you are dealing with sparse arrays -- well if you are, you're already in a state of sin -- but if you are, then `forest` could have a value but not one at index 0.  If this is the case, you might prefer a version like this:

```js
const forestHasWoods = where ({
  value: any (pathSatisfies (complement (isEmpty), ['props', 'forest']))
})
```